# When I call, I dont want other party to record my voice.How can I do that?

Tags: call-recording

When I call, I don't want other party to record my voice. How can I do that?

Comment: Not possible. If the other party installs an app that can record calls or if his ROM permits recording of calls, there is nothing *you* can do about it

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything about it but as a precaution you can follow some tips

- Do not use cellular calls for such sensitive calls because call recording for such calls is easily available and some OEM such as Xiomi have default settings for do so.

Not to mention bug is SS7 protocol for cellular communications.

- Use some other method for call like skype, whatsapp or hangout.

I have not seen any method to record these calls but this is not a full proof solution just a precaution. He can easily record it via putting call on loudspeaker and recording it form another device.

But you will be alert if someone does this because there will be echo of your own voice on loudspeaker.